# Using D3 Liquid Fill Gauge with React causes re-render issues

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

So I managed to incorporate this D3 Liquid Fill Gauge into my ReactJS project, but I'm having issues with react re-rendering the component when the percentage is changed causing duplicate gauges to render rather than one to update the percentage.

I have a working JS Bin to show what I mean.
http://jsbin.com/fezifotava/1/edit?js,output

In this case, when I click on the gauge it changes the percentage and calls the re-render method instead of just changing the value of the excising one.

This is the Liquid Fill Gauge I'm using: http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6

Thanks!

Edit:
I forgot to mention, that it doesn't even change the fill level when it re-renders. All that is being changed is the percent displayed.

Comment: There's a `react-liquid-gauge` library that recreates the D3 feature but works well within react (from trendmicro): https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-liquid-gauge -- and I created a minimalist example here https://codesandbox.io/embed/hardcore-hofstadter-qvomk2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `react-faux-dom` (https://github.com/Olical/react-faux-dom). It will let you use most of those blocks examples without any code changes.

Comment: Got stuck with my laptop not working, so I haven't tried this yet. I'll keep you posted once I get this resolved :)